# Sort function not working as expected after putting getElementById this way

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, if-statement, getelementbyid

I'm a beginner figuring out my own first project but I can't get info about this case.

The application is supposed to receive data about a product, it's name, price, stock, number of sales and then sort them from the most sold to the less sold.

Here's the thing, I was trying to shorten how verbose the code was by putting this chunk this other way

so I went from this

```js
var balanceVenta = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();

  diseños.sort((a, b) => {
    return (a.amountSold < b.amountSold) ? 1 : -1
  });

  document.getElementById("name1").innerHTML = diseños[0].designName;
  document.getElementById("stock1").innerHTML = diseños[0].currentStock;
  document.getElementById("price1").innerHTML = "$" + diseños[0].priceEa;
  document.getElementById("sold1").innerHTML = diseños[0].amountSold;
  document.getElementById("lastProduction1").innerHTML = diseños[0].productionAmount;

  document.getElementById("name2").innerHTML = diseños[1].designName;
  document.getElementById("stock2").innerHTML = diseños[1].currentStock;
  document.getElementById("price2").innerHTML = "$" + diseños[1].priceEa;
  document.getElementById("sold2").innerHTML = diseños[1].amountSold;
  document.getElementById("lastProduction2").innerHTML = diseños[1].productionAmount;

  document.getElementById("name3").innerHTML = diseños[2].designName;
  document.getElementById("stock3").innerHTML = diseños[2].currentStock;
  document.getElementById("price3").innerHTML = "$" + diseños[2].priceEa;
  document.getElementById("sold3").innerHTML = diseños[2].amountSold;
  document.getElementById("lastProduction3").innerHTML = diseños[2].productionAmount;

}
```

to this

```js
var index = 0;

var balanceVenta = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();

  diseños.sort((a, b) => {
    return (a.amountSold > b.amountSold) ? 1 : -1
  });


  index++;
  var prefixName = "name";
  var prefixStock = "stock";
  var prefixPrice = "price";
  var prefixSold = "sold";
  var prefixLastProd = "lastProduction";

  document.getElementById(prefixName + index).innerHTML = diseños[index - 1].designName;
  document.getElementById(prefixStock + index).innerHTML = diseños[index - 1].currentStock;
  document.getElementById(prefixPrice + index).innerHTML = diseños[index - 1].priceEa;
  document.getElementById(prefixSold + index).innerHTML = diseños[index - 1].amountSold;
  document.getElementById(prefixLastProd + index).innerHTML = diseños[index - 1].productionAmount;

}
```

Everything works fine except for the sort function, which was working fine in the first hardcoded version but not working at all in the second one.

Pd: "diseños" is an Array which holds an object ("diseño" with no s) inside each index through this function

```js
let diseños = [];
const addDesign = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    let diseño = {
      designName: document.getElementById("textBox1").value,
      currentStock: document.getElementById("textBox2").value,
      productionAmount: document.getElementById("textBox3").value,
      priceEa: document.getElementById("textBox4").value,
      amountSold: document.getElementById("textBox5").value

    }
    diseños.push(diseño);
    document.forms[0].reset();
```

Can you guys help me out figure this one out?

Comment: `if(diseños.length == index ){` makes no sense. Shouldn't you be looping over the array?

Comment: i just realized it makes no sense, but when I loop over the array, it won't stop until it ends returning undefined in the next cases

Comment: the idea is to add one product at a time, and sort the new inputs acording to the old ones

Comment: Note that if `amountSold` is a number, you can just use `diseños.sort((a, b) => a.amountSold - b.amountSold)` for ascending and `diseños.sort((a, b) => b.amountSold - a.amountSold)` for descending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close; you just need to put the code in a loop over `diseños`. I also simplified the sort logic a little, assuming `amountSold` is a number. Swap the position of `a.amountSold` and `b.amountSold` to change ascending to descending.

```js
var balanceVenta = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();

  diseños.sort((a, b) => a.amountSold - b.amountSold);

  var prefixName = "name";
  var prefixStock = "stock";
  var prefixPrice = "price";
  var prefixSold = "sold";
  var prefixLastProd = "lastProduction";

  for (var index = 0; index < diseños.length; index++) {
    var suffix = index + 1;
    document.getElementById(prefixName + suffix).innerHTML = diseños[index].designName;
    document.getElementById(prefixStock + suffix).innerHTML = diseños[index].currentStock;
    document.getElementById(prefixPrice + suffix).innerHTML = diseños[index].priceEa;
    document.getElementById(prefixSold + suffix).innerHTML = diseños[index].amountSold;
    document.getElementById(prefixLastProd + suffix).innerHTML = diseños[index].productionAmount;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

make an object with all the properties you need, and then run this method over an array of your object every time you want to put it in order

```
var balanceVenta = diseños.OrderByDescending(x =>x.amountSold).ToList()
```

Comment: right, actually I'm sending each object (diseño) to the array (diseños) so in this case it should be diseños.OrderByDescending(x.amountSold > x.amountSold)

Comment: but still it does the same that it did with sort() it doesn't sort the order of the indexes according to the ammounts that I get in the .ammountSold property, which it did perfectly when I hardcoded the indexes and the getelementsbyId

Comment: @federico_531 The update I put works for me with c#

Comment: Not for me in javascript, but it must be me overseeing something

Comment: @federico_531 is it the typo "amountSold" from your original "ammountSold" view on the double m

Comment: Why is there a C# answer to a JavaScript question?

Comment: @HereticMonkey pretty sure that tag was added 11 hours after my answer. Thank you very much